# how to disable a div when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: typescript, angular-material, aurelia

i have the following checkbox

```
<md-checkbox checked.bind="addEventCommand.allDay" change.delegate="allday()">All Day</md-checkbox>
```

when the above is true i want to disable the div bellow

```
<div class="row" >
<md-input label="Start DateTime" value.bind="addEventCommand.startTime" ></md-input> 
<md-input label="End DateTime" value.bind="addEventCommand.endTime"></md-input>
</div>
```

i know in javascript i could just get the element and disable it. i am not sure how to do this in angular materialize and typescript

i have added this to my typescript

```
allday() {
        if (this.addEventCommand.allDay === true) {
            
        }
        
    }
```

i tried this

```
 <md-checkbox  ref="addEventCommand.allDay.check"checked.bind="addEventCommand.allDay" >All Day</md-checkbox>
```

and on the div i tried

```
<div class="row" disabled.bind="addEventCommand.allDay.check.checked"></div>
```

but it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ngModel to The checkbox, then hide that Using ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="toShow"> 
My content
</div>

<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="toShow">
```

ts

```
toShow = true;
```

Comment: thanks, this helped, but instead of using *ngIf="toShow" i used if.bind="toShow" and in ts i did the following toShow = true;

 setDisabled() {
  this.toShow = !this.toShow;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Input elements have a disabled property like checkbox, text input, etc. Div element is not an input element so it doesn't have a disabled property.

A solution is to create a simple CSS class named disabled

```
.disabled {
  background: gray;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="row" [class.disabled]="addEventCommand.allDay.check.checked"></div>
```